# didUpdateToLocation not called

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, cllocationmanager

I  have a very complicated problem with geolocation : the didupdatetolocation delegate method is not called which I'm not understand. 
[image]
this the code of the method:

```
 - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)pLocationManager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)pNewLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)pOldLocation {

        lGPSAccuracy = 0;

        // Stop trace record when the GPS Signal is poor or null
        if (pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy > GPS_POOR_SIGNAL || pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0){ return;}

        if (pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy > pNewLocation.verticalAccuracy) {
            lGPSAccuracy = pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
        } else {
            lGPSAccuracy = pNewLocation.verticalAccuracy;
        }

        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(traceRecorder:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:)]) {
            [self.delegate traceRecorder:self didUpdateToLocation:pNewLocation fromLocation:pOldLocation];
        }

        CLLocationCoordinate2D lUserLocation =  pNewLocation.coordinate;

        Boolean lLatitudeOK = (self.mMapSouthWest.latitude < lUserLocation.latitude) && (lUserLocation.latitude < self.mMapNorthEast.latitude);
        Boolean lLongitudeOK = (self.mMapSouthWest.longitude < lUserLocation.longitude) && (lUserLocation.longitude < self.mMapNorthEast.longitude);

        //IF USER IS OUT OF THE MAP

        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userPositionOnMap:)]) {
            if ( (!lLatitudeOK || !lLongitudeOK) ) {
                [self.delegate userPositionOnMap:NO];
            } else {
                [self.delegate userPositionOnMap:YES];
            }
        }

        if (![self isNewLocation:pNewLocation acceptableComparedToOldLocation:pOldLocation]) {
            return;
        }

        [self treatLocation:pNewLocation];
    }
```

when I read about this problem i found that this method is deprecated but it's still working on a old version of my project which is very abnormal.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `CLLocationManager` variable isn't a local variable. And call `startUpdatingLocation` after creating `CLLocationManager`. One of these 2 mistake can make `didUpdateToLocation` isn't called.

Try my code below

```
- (void) beginMonitoring {

    if (TracageAutomatic) {
        tracageAutomaticTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(tracageAutomaticTimeCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }
     if (self.mLocationManager == nil) {
        [self setMLocationManager: [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];
        [self.mLocationManager setDelegate:self];
        [self.mLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
        [self.mLocationManager setDistanceFilter:2.0f]; //Minimum distance to move in meters before calling location update.

        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
            //TODO: restore for iOS8
            [self.mLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
    }

    [self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    if ([self.mLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
        [self.mLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
    }
```

}

Comment: yes CLLocationManager is global variable and also the startUpdatingLocation is called after creating CLLocationManager

Comment: @WalidSassi add a break point and make sure this code is runned

Comment: yes i maked a break point and i added a picture for this but as you see the method is not called

Comment: @WalidSassi no, i mean add a break point to line ` [self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];` and check is it called or not ;)

Comment: @WalidSassi great. Now you can fix it ;)

Comment: It's because `TracageAutomatic` is true. You should check why `TracageAutomatic` is true.

Comment: i added traçage automatic to launch an automatic hike which is a special method that i added to do this

Comment: this the method to launch an automatic trace for the hike :

Comment: @WalidSassi i have updated my answer, you can try my code above

Comment: @WalidSassi Yes, replace the code in my answer with your code and try.

Comment: `[self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];` is called but `didupdatetolocation` isn't called?

Comment: @WalidSassi `[self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];` is called or not. Please read carefully and tell me. I think your problem is because `[self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];` method isn't called

Comment: yes it is called I will give you a link video to show the all running scenario

Comment: @WalidSassi i see, did you try to change you current location?

Comment: No i didn't should i do ??

Comment: Of course, it's called when you change device location `didUpdateToLocation` ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes I'm sure that i did this in the code of this method which is called in running perfectly

```
- (void) beginMonitoring {

    if (TracageAutomatic) {
        tracageAutomaticTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(tracageAutomaticTimeCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    } else {
        if (self.mLocationManager == nil) {
            [self setMLocationManager: [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]];
            [self.mLocationManager setDelegate:self];
            [self.mLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
            [self.mLocationManager setDistanceFilter:2.0f]; //Minimum distance to move in meters before calling location update.

            if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
                //TODO: restore for iOS8
                [self.mLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
        }

        [self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        if ([self.mLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
            [self.mLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the startupdatetolocation is called but the didupdatetolocation is not called and the automatic trace of the hike is not running !!!!

Answer (score 0):

this the method to launch an automatic hike :

```
- (void) tracageAutomaticTimeCalled{

    if (_mUserReachedTrackEnd){
        [tracageAutomaticTimer invalidate];
        tracageAutomaticTimer = nil;
    }

    [self treatLocation:[self.mTrackPoints objectAtIndex:tracageAutomaticCurrentIndex]];

    tracageAutomaticCurrentIndex += TracageAutomoticPas;
    if (tracageAutomaticCurrentIndex > [self.mTrackPoints count]){
        tracageAutomaticCurrentIndex = (int)([self.mTrackPoints count]-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add it to question, don't add new answer. I want to ask about `TracageAutomatic`

Comment: ok thank you but I didn't still wait to know why the updatetolocation is not called please

Answer (score 0):

thank you @truncdug. I resolved the problem by changing the deprecated didtoupdatelocations method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    if ([locations count]>0) {
        CLLocation *pNewLocation = [locations firstObject];
        CLLocation *pOldLocation = _currentLocation;

         _currentLocation = pNewLocation;

        lGPSAccuracy = 0;

        // Stop trace record when the GPS Signal is poor or null
        if (pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy > GPS_POOR_SIGNAL || pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0){ return;}

        if (pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy > pNewLocation.verticalAccuracy) {
            lGPSAccuracy = pNewLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
        } else {
            lGPSAccuracy = pNewLocation.verticalAccuracy;
        }

        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(traceRecorder:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:)]) {
            [self.delegate traceRecorder:self didUpdateToLocation:pNewLocation fromLocation:pOldLocation];
        }

        CLLocationCoordinate2D lUserLocation =  pNewLocation.coordinate;

        Boolean lLatitudeOK = (self.mMapSouthWest.latitude < lUserLocation.latitude) && (lUserLocation.latitude < self.mMapNorthEast.latitude);
        Boolean lLongitudeOK = (self.mMapSouthWest.longitude < lUserLocation.longitude) && (lUserLocation.longitude < self.mMapNorthEast.longitude);

        //IF USER IS OUT OF THE MAP

        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userPositionOnMap:)]) {
            if ( (!lLatitudeOK || !lLongitudeOK) ) {
                [self.delegate userPositionOnMap:NO];
            } else {
                [self.delegate userPositionOnMap:YES];
            }
        }


        if (![self isNewLocation:pNewLocation acceptableComparedToOldLocation:pOldLocation]) {
            return;
        }

        [self treatLocation:pNewLocation];


    }
}
```